# How to read the position of the specific argument in bat file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to provide as a wrapper to execute another bat file. I need to read the arguments from the command line and need to check the position of that argument.

For example: `Test.bat -i path/myinput -t path/myoutput`

In the script i am checking whether "-i" and "-t" option is specified or not

If it is specified,
    it will call another bat file `Main.bat In/path/myinput/ Out/path/myoutput/`
else
    it will call another bat file `Main.bat In/ Out/`

My script is working if i hard-code the position to read input path by using [%2]. But i don't want to restrict the user to follow same pattern. They can use option -t first then -i second. So i need to read the postion of "-i" and "-j"

some thing like 
    `if [%*]==[-i] ( SET inputpath=In/[%(getpos()+1)]/) else ( SET inputpath=In/)`.So that i can use like `Main.bat %inputpath% %Outputpath%`

Comment: Why wouldn't you just check the values of %1 and %3?

Comment: Unrelated - `/` introduces options in winbatch, `\\` is a path-separator

Answer (score 0):

Could this be helpful:

```
@echo off
set position=0
for %%a in (%*) do (
set /a position+=1
if "%%~a"=="-i" Goto :found
)
echo -i not found!
Goto eof

:found
echo Found as argument %position%
```

Loops through all arguments (`%*`) counts a variable up and checks whether the argument found equals your desired value. If found the loop gets broken and the position of the argument writen out.

Example usage:

> `myBat.bat abc def -i "not seen anymore"`
>
> Output: Found as argument 3
>
> `myBat.bat "works with spaces as well" -i`
>
> Output: Found as argument 2

To actually get the argument you can use this syntax:

```
call echo %%%myVar%
```

Full code:

```
@echo off
set position=0
for %%a in (%*) do (
set /a position+=1
if "%%~a"=="-i" Goto :found
)
echo -i not found!
Goto eof

:found
echo Found as argument %position%
set /a position=%position%+1
call set bs=%%%position%
echo %bs%
```

Comment: But how to read from the position. I tried like this `set bs=%(%position%)`. Basically it should perform like `set bs=%2`. which is reading 2nd arg. Which is not working

Comment: i used `set bs=%%%position%`. if i do echo %bs% it is %2. when i do `set bs=%2`. It is printing correct command line argument

Comment: do either `call echo %bs%` or `call set %%%position%`. The `call` is important as it does the following. Using the call the following is passed to echo / set: `echo %1` because everything gets evaluated. `%%` turns into `%` and `%position%` to set value.

Comment: Here my intention is to set "bs" as command line argument. that's the reason, i am getting the position of "-i" is found. Then i am doing +1 after option "i". Then i am trying to set bs on that arg. Example. `Test.bat -i mybuild`. I need to set bs=mybuild.

Comment: @Cool_Binami I added a full working code at the end. Test with "`myBat abc -i arg`" returned arg from the `echo`.